# Quick blox chat not authenticating

Tags: ios, quickblox

I am using quickblox in my app to do 1 to 1 chat.
The user is already login. 
But when I try to login the chat, I get the following error.

```
2014-03-31 12:42:09.532 MyChat[2175:3803] QBChat/didNotAuthenticate, error: <failure      xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><not-authorized/></failure>
2014-03-31 12:42:09.533 MyChat[2175:3803] -[QBContactList dealloc] -> 
2014-03-31 12:42:09.533 MyChat[2175:3803] QBChat/didDisconnect, error: (null)
```

What am I doing wrong.

```
QBUUser *currentUser = [QBUUser user];
[QBChat instance].delegate = self;
[[QBChat instance] loginWithUser:currentUser];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a right way,

**currentUser** instance is empty, you should set **ID** and **password** at least to login to Chat

For example

```
QBUUser *user = [QBUUser user];
user.ID = 979387;
user.password = @"userpass";
[[QBChat instance] loginWithUser:user];
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply , that was a terrible mistake i made , i know.

Comment: where can I get code for quickblox webRTC  for the swift.