# Getting not-authorized xmpp error on creating video chat

Tags: quickblox

I'm able to successfully setup quickblox and successfully create sessions and authenticate users, however as soon as I want to create a chat, I receive the following log erors:

> 2015-09-02 18:39:10.881 banter[4518:2302588] -[QBChat
> xmppStreamDidConnect:] -> Trying TLS...
>
> 2015-09-02 18:39:11.523 banter[4518:2302588] -[QBChat xmppStreamDidSecure:] -> isSecure: YES
>
> 2015-09-02 18:39:11.703 banter[4518:2302553] xmppStreamDidConnect
>
> 2015-09-02 18:39:11.800 banter[4518:2302554]
> QBChat/didNotAuthenticate, error:
>
> 2015-09-02 18:39:11.805 banter[4518:2302554] -[QBChat
> xmppStreamDidDisconnect:withError:] -> error: (null)

which seems as though there is something wrong with my account. In order to test this theory, I downloaded the sample app quickblox provides, ensured it runs (it does) and then changed the credentials in the sample app to my own (all 4 places -- app id, auth id, secret id, account id) and when rerunning it I got the same error.

Is there something I need to setup with my account to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured it out -- the authentication via my account forces me to use users by ID rather than user name (not sure exactly why this is,) so the old code which looked like:

```
var user = QBUUser()
user.login = "test2"
user.password = __REDACTED__
let resp = QBChat.instance().loginWithUser(user)
```

The new code looks like:

```
var user = QBUUser()
user.ID = 5144362
user.password = __REDACTED__
let resp = QBChat.instance().loginWithUser(user)
```

and now login proceeds correctly.

(N.B. Got the idea for trying ID from this answer: [Quick blox chat not authenticating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22755804/quick-blox-chat-not-authenticating))

Comment: Where do you get the ID from??

Comment: @SimonNicholls I believe that was created after I added a user to my system via a different method. I don't recall if I used their admin panel or some other route.